# Retrieve Future<list<DATA>> array, with JSON while fetching from API in Flutter

Tags: php, json, flutter, rest

I'm new in Flutter, and I have started with FlutKit packages.
Now I'm in trouble with an array LIST.
FlutKit use a list with static Json data to cache data at the beginning.
These list are: Products, Categories and Carts.
Beofre start the main app flutist preload these data using class ShoppingCache.

I have thought to create my new one list `LapsUser`.

So, I need to  populate it, retrieving data, NOT from a static JSON file (like Products, Categories and Carts), but via API directly from my cloud server "MariaDB" and parsing it via JSONs "utils."
After this I wish to populate a list like the previous one "the flutKit example", but I have only errors... after two enter day of browsing the web, without a solution, I'm here.

This is the error:

> Error (Xcode): lib/CloudDB/sql_laps_user_class.dart:53:39: Error: A value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'LapsUser'.

These are sources:

//FILE: shopping_constants.dart
//Directly from FlutKIT

```
import 'models/cart.dart';
import 'models/category.dart';
import 'models/product.dart';
import 'package:simracer002/CloudDB/sql_laps_user_class.dart';

class ShoppingCache {
  static List<Category>? categories;
  static List<Product>? products;
//==========================================
// This is my new list
  static List<LapsUser>? lapsUser;
//==========================================
  static List<Cart>? carts;

  static bool isFirstTime = true;
}
```

file: product.dart
Directly from FlutKIT

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:simracer002/extensions/string.dart';

class Product {
  String name, image, description;
  double price, rating;
  int review, quantity;
  Color color;
  bool favorite;

  Product(this.name, this.image, this.description, this.rating, this.price,
      this.review, this.quantity, this.color, this.favorite);

  static Future<List<Product>> getDummyList() async {
    dynamic data = json.decode(await getData());
    return getListFromJson(data);
  }

  static Future<Product> getOne() async {
    return (await getDummyList())[0];
  }

  static Product fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonObject) {
    String name = jsonObject['name'].toString();
    String image = jsonObject['image'].toString();
    String description = jsonObject['description'].toString();
    double rating = double.parse(jsonObject['rating'].toString());
    double price = double.parse(jsonObject['price'].toString());
    int review = int.parse(jsonObject['review'].toString());
    int quantity = int.parse(jsonObject['quantity'].toString());
    Color color = jsonObject['review'].toString().toColor;
    bool favorite = jsonObject['favorite'].toString().toBool();

    return Product(name, image, description, rating, price, review, quantity,
        color, favorite);
  }

  static List<Product> getListFromJson(List<dynamic> jsonArray) {
    List<Product> list = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++) {
      list.add(Product.fromJson(jsonArray[i]));
    }
    return list;
  }

  static Future<String> getData() async {
    return await rootBundle
        .loadString('lib/full_apps/shopping/data/products.json');
  }
}
```

file: products.json

```
[
  {
    "name": "Pink & Blue Top",
    "image": "assets/images/apps/shopping2/images/photo2.jpg",
    "description": "Cool, Windy weather is on its way. Send him out the door in a jacket he wants to wear. Warm Zipper Hoodie Jacket. Try it out to feel comfy",
    "rating": 4.5,
    "review": 125,
    "price": 150.0,
    "color": "#FFADAD",
    "quantity": 8,
    "favorite": true
  },
  {
    "name": "White off shoulder",
    "image": "assets/images/apps/shopping2/images/photo3.jpg",
    "description": "Cool, Windy weather is on its way. Send him out the door in a jacket he wants to wear. Warm Zipper Hoodie Jacket. Try it out to feel comfy",
    "rating": 3.5,
    "review": 125,
    "price": 135.5,
    "color": "#B1D4F8",
    "quantity": 5,
    "favorite": false
  },
  {
    "name": "Men's White Formal",
    "image": "assets/images/apps/shopping2/images/photo9.jpg",
    "description": "Cool, Windy weather is on its way. Send him out the door in a jacket he wants to wear. Warm Zipper Hoodie Jacket. Try it out to feel comfy",
    "rating": 3.5,
    "review": 125,
    "price": 99.99,
    "color": "#ffd6a5",
    "quantity": 10,
    "favorite": false
  }
]
```

This would be my file for my list lapsUser, that in theory must do something like "Product List (FlutKit)" from Json, but retrieving data from REST API-Json-PHP

Please note that all code and PHP for the final result:

```
final response = await http.get(httpsUri);
```

with all parameters, works perfectly if I use it directly, building a simple list in a
simple application outside this.

FILE: sql_laps_user_class.dart

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:simracer002/extensions/string.dart';

class LapsUser {

  String totalLaps;
  String sessionsTrack;
  String nikname;
  String userName;

  LapsUser({
    required this.totalLaps,
    required this.sessionsTrack,
    required this.nikname,
    required this.userName
  });


  static Future<List<LapsUser>> getSessionsList(String userName) async {
    String userPass = "myDummyPass";
    String IduserCloud = "3";

    var httpsUri = Uri(
        scheme: 'https',
        host: 'www.myDummyWeb.net',
        path: '/wp-content/sql_laps_user.php',
        queryParameters: {'user': userName, 'pass': userPass, 'IduserCloud': IduserCloud});

    final response = await http.get(httpsUri);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      dynamic data = json.decode(response.body);
      final List successList = data["responseBody"]["success"];
      final List<LapsUser> fullSessionsUser = [];

      successList.forEach((success) {
//==>> The next line is line 53 (where is my  error)
        final LapsUser sessionsUser = {
          "totalLaps": success["Total_laps"],
          "sessionsTrack": success["Sessions_track"],
          "nikname": success["Nikname"],
          "userName": success["UserName"],
        };

        fullSessionsUser.add(sessionsUser);
      });

      return fullSessionsUser;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to fetch sessions counter detail');
    }
  }
}
```

Here FlutKit Load data during the startup

```
 goToFullApp() async {
    // TODO.MAX: NOTA: qui precarica i dati di tutta l'APP
    ShoppingCache.products = await Product.getDummyList();
    ShoppingCache.lapsUser = await LapsUser.getSessionsList('myDummyUser');
    ShoppingCache.categories = await Category.getDummyList();
    ShoppingCache.carts = await Cart.getDummyList();
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));

    Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pushReplacement(
      PageRouteBuilder(
          transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 2),
          pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => FullApp()),
    );
  }
```

I can't understood where is my error, and I have tried a lot to different solution, to parse JSON from REST API, but nothing!

Comment: What part of the error is not clear to you in context of your code?

Comment: Hi hakre, thanks you. I'am new in Flutter/Dart, and I'm not sure what the error means, so I don't know what I have to do to solve. I have made a double check comparing original Product Class, but again I don't know what to do to solve.
Thanks if you can told to me what is my novice mistake.

Answer (score 0):

After one more day of study, I have found my solution with this:

```
  return (json.decode(response.body) as List)
      .map((item) => LapsUser.fromJson(item))
      .toList();
```

Final working Class

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:extensions/string.dart';

class LapsUser {

  String totalLaps;
  String sessionsTrack;
  String nikname;
  String userName;

  LapsUser(
      this.totalLaps,
      this.sessionsTrack,
      this.nikname,
      this.userName);


  static Future<List<LapsUser>> getSessionsList(String userName) async {
    String userPass = "myDummyPass";
    String IduserCloud = "3";

    var httpsUri = Uri(
        scheme: 'https',
        host: 'www.myWebSite.net',
        path: '/wp-content/sql_laps_user.php',
        queryParameters: {'user': userName, 'pass': userPass, 'IduserCloud': IduserCloud});

    final response = await http.get(httpsUri);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // ==>> SOLUTION!
      return (json.decode(response.body) as List)
          .map((item) => LapsUser.fromJson(item))
          .toList();

    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to fetch LapsUser');
    }
  }
    
  static LapsUser fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonObject) {
    String totalLaps = jsonObject["Total_laps"].toString();
    String sessionsTrack = jsonObject["Sessions_track"].toString();
    String nikname = jsonObject["Nikname"].toString();
    String userName = jsonObject["UserName"].toString();

    return LapsUser(totalLaps, sessionsTrack, nikname, userName);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "Total_laps": totalLaps,
    "Sessions_track": sessionsTrack,
    "Nikname": nikname,
    "UserName": userName,
  };
}
```